# How much LIMIT affect neo4j "allShortestPaths" cypher query performance

Tags: neo4j

I have learned that how much higher will your LIMIT be, how much higher DbHits will be done during the Execution Plan,and neo4j is using A* algorithm for "allShortestPaths" query.

My first question is dose LIMIT also affect neo4j "allShortestPaths" query.If it does affect, how much it affects, why it affect?

I have do some test.but i haven't found the obvious evidence that the LIMIT affect performance as we expect

[EDITED]

My test query:

```
MATCH
  (node1:E { eid:"c953fc2d-55fc-4239-910e-ae6e41b3648d" }),
  (node2:E { eid:"e8cdf5e0-97ad-4e1e-a8e4-29358f8a9866" }),
  p = allShortestPaths((node1)-[*]-(node2))
RETURN p
LIMIT 25;
```

Comment: Can you share some of your test queries? You can drop a `LIMIT` in a _lot_ of places in a Cypher query, particularly when combined with `WITH`.

Comment: ok, My test queries is as follow:
MATCH (node1:E { eid:"c953fc2d-55fc-4239-910e-ae6e41b3648d" }),(node2:E { eid:"e8cdf5e0-97ad-4e1e-a8e4-29358f8a9866" }), p = allShortestPaths((node1)-[*]-(node2))
RETURN p LIMIT 25                                                                                   
My query is just finding the shortest paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `LIMIT` in you test query does not limit the amount of work done by `allShortestPaths`; instead, it just limits the number of results you get back.

The only way to affect the amount of work done by `allShortestPaths` is by putting an upper bound on the length of the paths searched. For example, this query will only search paths with up to 5 relationships:

```
MATCH
  (node1:E { eid:"c953fc2d-55fc-4239-910e-ae6e41b3648d" }),
  (node2:E { eid:"e8cdf5e0-97ad-4e1e-a8e4-29358f8a9866" }),
  p = allShortestPaths((node1)-[*..5]-(node2))
RETURN p
LIMIT 25;
```

By the way, to speed up the matching of the end nodes you should [create an index](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-schema-index) on `:E(eid)`.

Comment: thank you for your advice,but I have creat index.         **1** can i consider that the **LIMIT** in allShortestPaths query almost doesn't affect the performance,but  **LIMIT** still work in other query.
**2**why the "LIMIT"  doesn't limit the amout of work. In the **allShortestPaths**   algorithm,dose it search all the shortest paths at the same time rather than one by one. how it works?